# React TypeScript: TS2739: Type '{ children: Element; }' is missing the following properties from type 'AppStateContextProps': lists, getTasksByListId

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I'm learning how to use typescript with React. The following code is to implement context.

*AppStateContext.tsx*

```js
import React, { createContext, useContext, FC } from "react";

type AppStateContextProps = {
  lists: List[];
  getTasksByListId(id: string): Task[];
  children?: React.ReactNode;
};

type Task = {
  id: string;
  text: string;
};

type List = {
  id: string;
  text: string;
  tasks: Task[];
};

export type AppState = {
  lists: List[];
};

const appData: AppState = {
...
};

const AppStateContext = createContext<AppStateContextProps>(
  {} as AppStateContextProps
);

export const AppStateProvider = (props: AppStateContextProps) => {
  const { lists } = appData;

  const getTasksByListId = (id: string) => {
    return lists.find((list) => list.id === id)?.tasks || [];
  };

  return (
    <AppStateContext.Provider value={{ lists, getTasksByListId }}>
      {props.children}
    </AppStateContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

When I try to wrap `<App />` component with `AppStateProvider` I get the following error:

```bash
TS2739: Type '{ children: Element; }' is missing the following properties from type 'AppStateContextProps': lists, getTasksByListId
```

*Index.tsx*

```js
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom/client";
import "./index.css";
import { App } from "./App";
import reportWebVitals from "./reportWebVitals";
import { AppStateProvider } from "./state/AppStateContext";

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(
  document.getElementById("root") as HTMLElement
);
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <AppStateProvider>
      <App />
    </AppStateProvider>
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

What's the issue?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using the type of `AppStateContextProps` for the `props` of `AppStateProvider` component here:

```js
export const AppStateProvider = (props: AppStateContextProps) => {
```

you're saying that when you use `<AppStateProvider>` you'll be supplying it with children, as well as a `list` and `getTasksByListId` prop. However, you're not doing that when you use your component and are only supplying the children, not the `list` or `getTaksByListId` props (which is what your error is complaining about):

```
                v--- missing `list` & `getTaksByListId`
<AppStateProvider>
  <App /> // <--- this passes as the `children` prop to `AppStateProvider`
</AppStateProvider>
```

It actually looks like you don't want to pass these as props to `AppStateProvider`, and instead just have them as defined as part of the context value. I suggest creating a new type for your `AppStateProvider` component's props, and then remove the `children` from the context value props:

```
type ChildrenProps = {
  children?: React.ReactNode
};

type AppStateContextProps = {
  lists: List[];
  getTasksByListId(id: string): Task[];
  // removed: children?: React.ReactNode;
};

...

export const AppStateProvider = (props: ChildrenProps) => {
```